# Check whether a Python function is yet to be specified (ellipsis)

Tags: python, ellipsis

Is there any easy way to evaluate at runtime if a function has been specified or not?
for example, i have a function/method declared:

```
def func_to_be_implemented():
    ...
```

I would like to have function to check whether it has been specified or not like:

```
def function_is_defined(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> bool:
    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably use `raise NotImplementedError` instead of `...`.

Comment: Do you want to know if it's been _defined_, or if the function body is _something other than ellipse_?  Those are very different.

Comment: I am a little confused about what you mean. Python does not distinguish between function declaration and function definition. What's the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: If the function hasn't even been _defined_, then this task is impossible, because the calling code will encounter a NameError.

Comment: thank for your prompt feeback, you are right, 'undefined' is not the right word. I edited my original to clarify it should be 'not specified',

Comment: After lots of googling, i came up with a solution.  @JohnGordon, your initial question made me thing of just evaluate if the func code ends with  "..."  to check for that, about rising NotImplementedError, this was not an option sicnce its about dynamic programing,  and it will be the package user who will be declaring the function, so i found more friendly/elegant to do it using an ellipsis intead of raising an error. So using inspect library i got this:  def function_is_defined(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> bool:
    return getsource(func).split()[-1] == "..."

Comment: Be aware, using the inspect module is *a huge performance hit*

Comment: agree. but in this case it will only be called one time per class (not instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon suggestions and for the purposes declared (interfaz/library), i ended up using the inspect module:

```
from inspect import getsource

def function_is_defined(func) -> bool:
        return getsource(func).split()[-1] not in ["...", "pass"]
```

Notes about usage:
The rskattr decorator adds, cache, validation and getters/setter funcionality.
if the decorated function is defined, it will assing and cache the result of it, as an attribute.
This property/attribute can also be complemented with a complex setter (the underscored function below the property) whenever it runs, it overwrites the property value and gets cached for the next retrieval.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First a clarification:

Python does not distinguish between function declaration and definition, unlike some languages (C/C++). A python function is always defined at its definition site. The use of pass, or the ellipsis is just syntax for a function with no statements, necessary because of Python's use of significant whitespace.

In principle, you could determine if a function has no statements by inspecting it using the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect

def fun():
    pass

source = inspect.getsource(fun)
# source is now the string "def fun():\n.  pass"
```

Or by inspecting the function's bytecode using its **code** property. However you don't actually want to do this. Let me explain why.

pass/... does not belong in production code outside of certain special cases involving libraries that emulate interfaces and abstract classes from nominally typed languages, and empty callbacks. If you are having trouble figuring out which of your functions have statements, you need to clean up your codebase. On the other hand if you are trying to do something clever to avoid calling an empty function, it's going to be substantially more expensive then calling it, which will be very cheap.

The core purpose of a function is to encapsulate logic. The caller of a function should not need to know the implementation of the function, only that it works.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the clarification and very clear explanation on usage. in my case the intendd usage is for a library, specifically an extesnion of @property decorator. I will be marking my own answer as correct as it povides what is requested, but yours is good as well.

Comment: Sure. I still very strongly suspect that you would be better served not doing this. Remember that an empty function just syntactic sugar for a function that just returns None, since in Python all functions return a value.

Comment: Given i can paste pictures here, i have added further context  to the answer,  maybe you can propose another way of achieving the desired result...

Comment: I think I am suggesting that your desired result should be to treat empty functions the same as any other function. An empty function is still a function. Don't do the check at all just treat it like any other function. Cache the result (None). The mistake here is thinking of empty functions as somehow different from non empty ones. Logically `def foo(): pass` and `def foo(): return None` are identical.